# Unresponsive FreeBSD kldload process locks up whole system

Tags: freebsd, operating-system

Newly installed FreeBSD 12.1 and 11.4 immediately freezes when loading oce by running `kldload if_oce`. The whole system becomes locked up at this time. CTRL+c and CTRL+z don't work.

What is the starting point to find out the problem cause?

Why does the process make the whole FreeBSD unresponsive and the only option is to reboot?

I already encountered such problem with `mount` and zfs operations.

Comment: This seems like a bug if it happens on fresh installations, the best idea might be to report it at FreeBSD Bugzilla: https://bugs.freebsd.org/

Comment: It's loading a kernel module for Emulex OneConnect network interface. So if there's a bug happening in kernel, it can possibly affect anything.